# IText visualization of components

Tags: java, itext

I state that I use NetBeans 8.2. I need to transfer a jframe (which represents an invoice) on a paragraph of IText. Everything works and is displayed. However, I get that the writings and details of the pdf I created are not well defined and displayed.

For example, the strings seem to have a shaded effect so that instead of being only black, they have gray shades. It is particularly annoying when I print: the smaller text is not readable. The same effect does not occur in the video display.

I tried modifying the jframe size and scaling the graphic2d instance. Then I returned to normal size and I modified the scale of the paragraph and so I got a result a bit 'better but not satisfactory.

Any suggestions?

Edit: this is the code of the method that manages the creation of the paragraph:

```
private Paragraph creaParPdf(float scaleFactorW, float scaleFactorH) throws BadElementException, IOException {
    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(fatt.getWidth(), fatt.getHeight(), 
        BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D img2D = img.createGraphics();
    img2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
        RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    fatt.paint(img2D); 
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph(); 
    com.itextpdf.text.Image itextImg = 
        com.itextpdf.text.Image.getInstance(img, Color.white, false);
    itextImg.scaleAbsolute(PageSize.A4.getWidth()*scaleFactorW, PageSize.A4.getHeight()*scaleFactorH);
    p.add(itextImg);
    return p;
}
```

And this is the code of the method that manages the creation of the pdf:

```
public void printPDF() throws FileNotFoundException, DocumentException, SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, IOException{
    fatt = this;
    Document d = new Document(PageSize.A4,10,10,10,10);
    d.setMargins(10, 10, 0, 10);
    String salvPath = "C:\\"+cliente+".pdf";
    filePDF = new File(salvPath);
    filePDF.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            if (filePDF.exists())
                out.println("Il file " + salvPath + " esiste");
            else try {
                if (filePDF.createNewFile())
                    out.println("Il file " + salvPath + " è stato creato");
                else
                    out.println("Il file " + salvPath + " non può essere creato");
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                getLogger(JFrameStart.class.getName()).log(SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
    FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream (salvPath);
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(d, fs);
    writer.setFullCompression();
    d.open ();
    try {            
        float scaleFactorW = 0.98f;
        float scaleFactorH = 0.98f;
        float offset = 0.0f;
        p = creaParPdf(scaleFactorW,scaleFactorH);
    } catch (BadElementException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JFrameTracc.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    d.add(p); 
    d.close();     
}
```

This is the final result, by printing the pdf you can see how the smaller parts are practically illegible:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ov4WD.jpg)

Comment: This sounds like an interesting puzzle! Are you able to provide a minimal amount of code that readers can use to reproduce your problem?

Comment: yes, edit with the methods that interest you

Comment: Why don't you use the itext direct `Graphics2D` support? Rendering text to a bitmap and then embedding the bitmap into a pdf always results in worse quality than rendering text directly to a pdf.

Comment: could you give me an example of how to do it?

Comment: I recreated the whole bill with itext and the various cells and tables ... The result is what I wanted even if the construction is cumbersome. So I solved and I advise you to work directly with it if you want to get pdf sheets, the results are much better indeed ..